# Validation not working properly with ng-model-options = { updateOn: 'submit' }

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to  ng-model-options = { updateOn: 'submit' } so I can perserve the model until it is submitted (that way you can cancel out and not affect the model).

The problem I have is the validation is only checking against the ng-model rather than the form input.

Is there any way I can validate the form before its updated the model?

HTML:

```
<form name="form" 
        ng-submit="vm.update(vm.action)" 
        ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" novalidate >

    <label>Subject</label>
    <input name="subject" required ng-model="vm.action.body.subject"/>
    <div ng-messages="form.subject.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">You must enter a subject.</div>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

See codepen for a clearer explanation of the behaviour: http://codepen.io/tknz/pen/vGjajo/?editors=1010

- If you add a body, validation will fill for required
- If you remove the subject, the required validation will still pass

Is there a way around this? Or a better solution?

Comment: If you want achieve `cancel` behavior, better use `vm.action.body = {}` in `cancel` function.

Comment: I don't want to empty it, I want to preserve its old value.

Comment: Ok, when better use `var oldBody = angular.copy(vm.action.body);`. Then in `cancel` function `vm.action.body = oldBody `. This solution will not break validation.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a really thorny issue and one that makes using `updateOn: submit` to maintain a clean model until submission difficult. There are a few connected problems. The first is that `updateOn: submit` actually means do no validation at all until submission. There is an initial validation done on the way into the form and this is the only validation available as you move through the form. So if your opening form has invalid fields, your form will be marked as invalid as soon you move out of a field and will remain so until you submit.

One possible way around this is to call the exposed `$validate` method on the input control, say via ng-blur. This would give a manual validation of the control as you leave it. If you look at the code for the built-in validations, they are actually validating on the `$viewValue` rather than the `$modelValue`. So in theory this should work! But there are two issues. Firstly, the `$validate` method actually forces a model update if the `$viewValue` is out of sync with the `$modelValue`. I imagine that code is older than the idea of `updateOn: submit` and they didn't really envisage a scenario where having the two out of sync is the desired behaviour. The other problem is even more fundamental as the method actually uses an internal value called `$$lastCommittedViewValue`. I can't quite figure out why it is doing that, instead of just taking the actual `$viewValue`, but the end result is that in an `updateOn: submit` situation the `$$lastCommittedViewValue` never changes as the viewValue is only committed on the submit.

So the only official, documented way out of this isn't going to work. Looking at the code however, there is a fairly simple, though undocumented, way around this. The `$validate` method does some preliminary setup and then calls an internal method `$$runValidators`. This goes through the 3 possible sources of validators, the parsers (an historic artifact I think) and the sync and async validators. It is handy enough to call this directly with the real `$viewValue` instead of the last committed one. Set up a function like this in the form controller :

```
        validateNoUpdate(control) {
        control.$$runValidators(control.$modelValue, control.$viewValue,
            function(allValid) {
                console.log("In $$runValidators, allValid : ", allValid);
                // Any post validation code required can be entered here
        });
    }
```

and call it in the input control like this :

```
<input id="newClientName" name="newClientName"
   ng-maxlength="5"
   ng-required="true"
   ng-blur="$ctrl.validateNoUpdate(clientForm.newClientName)"
   ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" ng-model="$ctrl.client.name">
```

I wouldn't normally contemplate using an undocumented call like that, but I really hate the idea of cloning the form object and copying it back on cancel - it just seems fraught with potential issues. And in this particular case, Angular 1.x is coming to end of life so it is less likely that `runValidators` will be dropped or re-purposed. Also note that it is presumably possible to recreate `runValidators` in your code by directly accessing the (offically) exposed parsers/syncValidators and aSyncValidators. But the code looks a tad hairy and I'm happy enough to take my changes with `runValidators` until I migrate the whole thing to Angular 2.

Edit - It might be handier to do it as a directive (and this is one of the few situations where you might still use a directive over a component in 1.5+), as follows:

```
.directive('validateViewOnBlur', function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }
            element.on('blur', function() {
                ngModel.$$runValidators(ngModel.$modelValue, ngModel.$viewValue,
                    function(allValid) {
                        console.log("In $$runValidators, allValid : ", allValid);
                        // Any post validation code required can be entered here
                    });
            });
        }
    };
```